# shell command to change file and save

Tags: shell, awk, vim, sed

I want to modify file content with **shell script** like replace the line 3 in file with a new string, and then **save to the original file**. Can anyone give advice to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unusual to do that with vim from a shell script, but since you asked:

```
vim -es '+3s/.*/a new string' '+wq' file
```

Usually, you would chose another tool like (`sed -i` is in-place edit):

```
sed -i '3s/.*/a new string/' file
```

Or with awk

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==3{$0="a new string"}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Unix-like system, you can use `sed` to replace the content of specific line. For example, below command will replace the 3rd line with "HelloWorld" in text.txt file.

```
sed -i '3c HelloWorld' text.txt
```

In case you only want to change part of 3rd line content, you can use :

```
sed -i '3s/aaa/bbb/' text.txt
```

this will only replace string "aaa" into "bbb" in 3rd line.

Comment: I would recommend using `-i.bak` in order to create a backup before performing the change. Or `cp text.txt{,-bak}` before using sed.

Answer (score 2):

`ed` would be more appropriate than `sed` or `vim`, as it is designed to edit files in-place programmatically. (`sed` is the **s**tream version of `ed`; `-i` is a non-standard extension.)

```
printf '3s/.*/new stuff/\nw\n' | ed my_file.txt
```